# How to obtain all subclasses (of a specific class) defined by a module?

Tags: python, module, subclass

Given a module `module` and a class `MyClass`, how to obtain a list of all subclasses of `MyClass` defined in `module`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [inspect.getmembers()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers). Assuming you have in `mymodule.py`:

```
class A(object):
    pass


class B(A):
    pass


class C(A):
    pass
```

here's how you can get all subclasses of `A`:

```
import inspect
import mymodule
from mymodule import A

def is_subclass(o):
    return inspect.isclass(o) and issubclass(o, A)


print inspect.getmembers(mymodule, predicate=is_subclass)
```

or, in short `lambda` form:

```
print inspect.getmembers(mymodule,  
                         predicate=lambda o: inspect.isclass(o) and \
                                             issubclass(o, A))
```

Comment: better to use `inspect.isclass(object)` and better still not to shadow the builtin `object`. e.g. `inspect.getmembers(unittest, lambda o: inspect.isclass(o) and issubclass(o, unittest.TestCase))`

Comment: I could swear `issubclass(o,A)` didn't work in my previous test which is why I used `A in o.__mro__` instead. Can't reproduce that though... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is `inspect.getmembers(mymodule, predicate=something)` basically `[getattr(mymodule, name) for name in dir(mymodule) where something(getattr(mymodule, name)]`?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler yup, see [source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/inspect.py#L251).

Answer (score 1):

```
classes = ()
for name in dir(module):
    obj = getattr(module, name)
    try:
        # obj.__mro__ raises AttributeError on non-class
        if MyClass in obj.__mro__ and obj is not MyClass:
            classes += (obj,)
        #else:
        #    print name, "is no subclass of", MyClass
    except AttributeError:
        #print name, "is no class"
        pass  # you might of course use an if hasattr(obj, '__mro__') instead
```

Not pretty, but works. Alternatives are welcome though...

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
>>> def f(module):
...     things = [getattr(module, x) for x in dir(module)]
...     return [x for x in things if type(x) == type]
...
>>> import datetime
>>> f(datetime)
[<type 'datetime.date'>, <type 'datetime.datetime'>, <type 'datetime.time'>, <type 'datetime.timedelta'>, <type 'datetime.tzinfo'>]
```

Comment: Nice and concise - though you need to add a `and issubclass(x, myClass)` to the return statement - I should have made the question title consistent with the body, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

maybe try pyclbr module — Python class browser support

http://pymotw.com/2/pyclbr/

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit please? Though in the light of the other two brief answers this might be overkill...

Comment: ...though this might become useful in another context, thanks for the link

Comment: just tried to point to an existing solution (depending on a situation context can be an overkill I do agree, I just have a tendency to try not to reinvent). it provides by default a bit more options (methods, lines) and takes all from the src itself.